npm: refer to source repository in scripts installed via `npm install -g`
Say I have the following in my package.json:
{
  "bin": {
     "my-command": "bin/my_command.sh"
  }
}

Then after installing with npm install -g I can run my-command from anywhere assuming my PATH is set up correctly. However, from my_command.sh, how can I reference the directory into which my project is installed? For example, say I have a config file that I would like to read in my_command.sh and have the following project layout:
my-project/
├── bin
│   └── my_command.sh
├── config.yml
└── package.json

Is that possible? If so, how? My original motivation for this was that I would like to "alias" cd $SOME_DIR/my-project && npm run dev to a command that I can run from anywhere but for that a script would need to know where my-project is located and I can't figure out how to do that.
